# Select all elements but the last

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I need to select all elements of a div but the last of this code:

```
<div class="menu">
    <div>
       <a class="link" href="/">link 1</a>
       <div class="subMenu">
           <a class="link" href="/">link 2</a>
           <a class="link" href="/">link 3</a>
           <a class="link" href="/">link 4</a>
       </div>
       <a class="link" href="/">link 5</a>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have tried `.menu .link:not(:last-child)` but the `link 4` is selected as the last child but I want that the last child to be `link 5`. How can I do it?

Thanks you.

Comment: Have you tried adding a class to the div inside `<div class='menu'>` and referencing the `.link` class within it, not the menu div?

Comment: You need an extra selector for inbricated element  example`.menu .link:not(:last-child), .subMenu .link {color:red;}`

Comment: @G-Cyr thanks you! Your solution works like a charm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happens because the link 4 is also the `:last-child` or `:last-of-type` of the `.subMenu` div. You can do it like this instead:

```css
.menu > div > .link:not(:last-of-type),
.subMenu > .link {color:#f00}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <div>
    <a class="link" href="#">link 1</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
      <a class="link" href="#">link 2</a>
      <a class="link" href="#">link 3</a>
      <a class="link" href="#">link 4</a>
    </div>
    <a class="link" href="#">link 5</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Notes:

- the examples below will also work when your last child is a submenu.
- I assumed that your empty `<div>` was a typo
- the solution uses the [direct children selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors) (`.parent > .direct-children`)

---

You could do that:

```css
.menu > .link:not(:last-child),
.menu > .subMenu:not(:last-child) .link {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
Last is a single link:

<div class="menu">
    <a class="link" href="/">link 1</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
        <a class="link" href="/">link 2</a>
        <a class="link" href="/">link 3</a>
        <a class="link" href="/">link 4</a>
    </div>
    <a class="link" href="/">link 5</a>
</div>

<br />


Last is a submenu:

<div class="menu">
    <a class="link" href="/">link 1</a>
    <a class="link" href="/">link 2</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
        <a class="link" href="/">link 3</a>
        <a class="link" href="/">link 4</a>
        <a class="link" href="/">link 5</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

But I'd suggest to do the inverse:

```css
.menu .link {
  color: red;
}

.menu > :last-child,
.menu > :last-child .link {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
Last is a single link:

<div class="menu">
    <a class="link" href="/">link 1</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
        <a class="link" href="/">link 2</a>
        <a class="link" href="/">link 3</a>
        <a class="link" href="/">link 4</a>
    </div>
    <a class="link" href="/">link 5</a>
</div>

<br />


Last is a submenu:

<div class="menu">
    <a class="link" href="/">link 1</a>
    <a class="link" href="/">link 2</a>
    <div class="subMenu">
        <a class="link" href="/">link 3</a>
        <a class="link" href="/">link 4</a>
        <a class="link" href="/">link 5</a>
    </div>
</div>
```